# can not install ad-hoc ipa MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode4.5, ad-hoc-distribution, preflight

I using a CI system to build ipa automatically.

Basically I called this command line in build script:

`xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v $APP -o $Output --sign "$Company_name" --embed "$Provision_path"`

It works well before till after I update xcode to 4.5.1 and change the $Provision_path to a new path.

The ipa can not installed after that, the error look like:

```
<Error>: 0x1c1000 handle_install: Install of "$apppath.ipa" requested by itunesstored
<Error>: 0x1c1000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing $appID
<Error>: Nov 16 10:08:31  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorSHA1 IssuerCommonName]
<Error>: Nov 16 10:08:33  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
<Error>: developer cert trust result = 5
<Error>: 0x1c1000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.EuYJEL/foo_extracted/Payload/name.app/name: 0xe8008018
<Error>: 0x1c1000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.EuYJEL/foo_extracted/Payload/name.app
<Error>: 0x2ff9a000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
<Error>: 0x1c1000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
<Error>: 0x1c1000 handle_install: API failed
```

I check the build log, the difference between this time as last time is the $SignName

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "$SignName" --resource-rules=*** --entitlements ***
```

I believe the `$SignName` is exactly the same with the same as `$Company_name` in the command line.

But currently, the `$SignName` is something like `e38e96a4asfsdd779db94ceasdfg24d9assdf898`.
Do anyone have a clue what is the possible problem?

Comment: After keep the $SignName exactly the same (with `iPhone Distribution:` prefix) both in automatic build script (the command line) and the project settings. The ipa can be successful launched. I still don't know why it can work before.